# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer spring framework

Tags: java, spring

When I am running my code the Console shows the following error

> "Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for
>   C:\Users\Ankit
>   Singh\Downloads\spring-framework-5.1.9.RELEASE\libs\spring-context-indexer-5.1.9.RELEASE-sources.jar
>   Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider
>   class
>   org.springframework.context.index.processor.CandidateComponentsIndexer
>   not in module

1. Default Package delete.
2. Reinstalled Spring library
3. Two different way to call beans

Can someone suggested whats wrong in my system??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a default package, right? I have had the same error as you...
Listen, dude, you can try to click: your project name-properties-java build path, move your external jar(s) from module-path to classpath. Then, you can run the code again.